# jquery kill long-running .each function

Tags: jquery, each

I'm using this to sequentially fadeIn a stack of div's:

```
   $('#headerwrapper div').each(function(i) {
         $(this).delay(999 + (i * 999)).fadeIn(); 
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2pCv/3/

I'm trying to figure out how to stop it via .scroll. (Pause/resume would be nice, but after searching around and trying dozens of things, I'm ready to let go of wanting that much.)

Here's the scroll function:

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
               $('#headerwrapper').fadeOut();
        } else {
               $('#headerwrapper').fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

The reason it seems so important to be able to kill the .each function is the finished
product is going to be loading dozens of images, and to me, if those aren't even in 
the viewport the function should just stop so as to free up processing/memory.

I have no idea is .fadeOut of the parent div is enough to actually stop/kill the .each function, or if it's still firing off continuously in the background for nothing. What's a more correct way to kill (or pause/resume if you're feeling generous) this .each function?

Comment: You can't stop the `.each()` function itself because it is synchronous code and your `.scroll()` handler won't be called until after `.each()` is finished. What you can stop is the multiple animations queued up by the code in the `.each()` - they're asynchronous so your `.scroll()` handler can be called before they've finished.

Answer (score 4):

This should be enough to end all queued effects on the divs of the header.

```
$("#headerwrapper div").finish()
```

In older versions of jQuery, use `.stop(true,true)` in place of `.finish()`

I wouldn't suggest attempting to resume it other than starting it over from the beginning.

Comment: I've tried stop, finish, dequeue, die, etc., but nothing seems to penetrate the .each functions force field. I did include a fiddle so if anyone wants to try to make this .each train stop...